# How can I disable the CTRL-ALT-DEL key combination completely on XP/Vista/7?

Tags: shell

I have been googling extensively to figure this out, and nobody seems to be able to give a direct answer.

Let me start by saying that I'm NOT talking about requiring CTRL-ALT-DEL to enter logon information.

I'm working on a golf simulator program which is used at golf centers. I need the ability to completely disable the CTRL-ALT-DEL key sequence so that the golf center customers can't get out of the program and access the computer at all. I realize there are other key combinations that need to be handled as well, we already have this entire feature working in XP, but we're going to be switching to Windows 7 soon, and CTRL-ALT-DEL is the only one that doesn't seem to work in Win7. I'd really like an all-around solution if at all possible.

This same program may also be installed on a client's personal computer for an in-home golf simulator, but the computers that really need this feature (golf center computers) are provided to the golf center by us, so would the best option be to write a new shell? I don't know anything about that at all, other than others that suggest writing a new shell for kiosk mode.

I'd really like a simpler option, like modifying the registry in some way. I have heard that you can remove some buttons from the menu screen that pops up, but unless I can remove pretty much all of them (including the shutdown/restart button in the bottom-right corner), this won't be enough of a solution for me.

Comment: pry off the ctrl, alt and delete keys.

Comment: If your app doesn't use one of Ctrl, Alt, or Del, you could always break that key on the keyboard itself. :-)

Comment: This is not a programming question and is likely to be migrated to Super User or Server Fault. That said, I'd advise looking into "kiosk mode" for Windows. My guess is that you can find an existing program to lock your computer into kiosk mode.

Comment: If virii do it, we know that we can do it ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Control+Alt+Delete without modifying GINA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917650/disable-controlaltdelete-without-modifying-gina)

Comment: @Will - not the most secure implementation, since all but the most easily foiled of adversaries will be aware of the ability to send keystrokes sans labeled keys. I advise going one step further and casting the exposed contacts or switches in some sort of [indestructible alloy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium).

Answer (score 3):

**Disable Ctrl-Alt-Del:**

Save the following text into a text file named *disableCtrlAltDel.reg*:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]
"Debugger"="Hotkey Disabled"
```

**Enable Ctrl-Alt-Del:**

Save the following text into a text file named *enableCtrlAltDel.reg*:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]
```

Double click either of them to enable / disable

Comment: Note that this seems to block *all access* to task manager for all users (including ctrl+shift+del).

Answer (score 1):

Disable Ctrl-Alt-Del:

1. Save the following text into a text file named `disable_Ctrl_Alt_Del.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,4d,e0,1d,e0,4b,e0,1d,00,\
  00,00,00,00
```

2. Double click either of them to disable

Answer (score -1):

Via Group Policy

Click on Start button, and type secpol.msc into Start Search box, and hit Enter to open the Local Security Policy Editor.
Navigate to Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options.
In the right pane, double click on Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL.
Select and set the radio button of Disabled.

Comment: This will disable the CTRL+ALT+DEL prompt on the logon screen, but won't actually disable the key combo altogether.